# how to check if there is no text in the textfield so that error message can b displayed

Tags: java

```
if(namefield.getText().compareTo("")==0)
```

Is this code above correct to check that no input is there in the **textfield** so that a error message can be generated?
provided have to use compareTo func only

Comment: try `equalsIgnoreCase` -->  `if(namefield.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(""))`

Comment: Have you tried `if(namefield.getText().isEmpty())` ?

Comment: Add required attribute in the textfield.

Answer (score 1):

to be more accurate

```
String data = nameField.getText()
if(data==null || data.length()==0)
{
//show error message here
}
```

Comment: @xenteros Care to elaborate? This can only produce an NPE if `nameField` is null

Comment: Exactly. No need to elaborate :)

Comment: @xenteros Like Michele commented on another answer here: if `nameField` is null, there is a design issue and it should throw a NPE. (fail fast, fail hard)

Comment: Why to check if data is null, when getText doesn't return a null.

Comment: how do you know what getText returns? We don't have any information about its type

Comment: here namefield contains a location which is of String type.Now question was to check if there is no location entered by user then have to produce an error message .Now can you help ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the namefield.getText() method is implemented in your platform. Since you didn't method which platform you are using. I suggest you can check the documentation.

Generally, when the namefield is not set, namefield.getText() will return a empty String which is "". So we don't need to check if it's null.

So we can check using following code:

```
if(namefield.getText().isEmpty()){}
```

which is same as following:

```
if(namefield.getText().length()==0){}
```

Because String.isEmpty() method is implemented as following:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
     return value.length == 0;
}
```

On the other hand, when the namefield.getText() can return null. You need to check null to avoid NPE.

```
String name = namefield.getText();
if(name==null || name.isEmpty()){}
```

---

Finally, if you want to check if the input string is whitespace, you can simply use String.trim() to remove the whitespace.

```
if(namefield.getText().trim().isEmpty()){}
```

or

```
String name = namefield.getText();
if(name==null || name.trim().isEmpty()){}
```

---

Even though we can use name.equals(""), I don't think it's the best way. Since in String.equals method, it firstly check if the objects are the same and then use the length to check if they're equal. However, when we get a text from a Textfield, the object will not be the same with the constant string "".

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                    return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
if((namefield.getText()== null) || (namefield.getText().length() == 0)){
  show error message
}
```

Comment: if(nameField.getText().comapreTo(" ")==0){message} but with this code its only shiwing exceptjon in thread "awt evnt queue 0" and nit the message

Comment: like if namefield is empty then it shouls display the error message ieJOptionPane.showMessage but its not doing it and rather only some exception in Commandprompt is coming NumberFormatException:for input string" "

Comment: @xenteros how ?

Comment: namefield can be a null

Comment: @xenteros I also don't see how, please explain

Comment: OK but in that case it menans that there is a design issue

Answer (score 0):

The method compareTo() is used for comparing two strings lexicographically. Each character of both the strings is converted into a Unicode value for comparison. If both the strings are equal then this method returns 0 else it returns positive or negative value. The result is positive if the first string is lexicographically greater than the second string else the result would be negative.

Instead use **equals()**

```
 if(namefield.getText().equals(null) || namefield.getText().equals(""))
    {
    //do this
    }
```

Comment: This leads to NPE

Comment: Don't use equals for checking if something is a null.